# How do I prevent Vim from indenting lines containing <screen/> XML tags?

Tags: filetype-xml

I edit a lot of Docbook files. `<screen/>` blocks are normally unindented in Docbook source code. How do I tell Vim to shift the `<screen>` tag to the very left when entering such tag?
After closing that block with `</screen>`, it would be nice to continue indenting as it was before the starting `<screen>`.
I use:

```
filetype plugin indent on
set smartindent
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

The filetype indentation rules (`filetype plugin indent on`) should take precedence over whatever `set smartindent` defines.

Is your filetype getting recognized?  What does `set filetype?` return?

I see in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` that .sgm and .sgml files are either recognized as sgml, sgmllnx, or docbk filetypes.  It depends on the text on the first line.

```
" SGML
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sgm,*.sgml
    \ if getline(1).getline(2).getline(3).getline(4).getline(5) =~? 'linuxdoc' |
    \   setf sgmllnx |
    \ elseif getline(1) =~ '<!DOCTYPE.*DocBook' || getline(2) =~ '<!DOCTYPE.*DocBook' |
    \   let b:docbk_type = "sgml" |
    \   let b:docbk_ver = 4 |
    \   setf docbk |
    \ else |
    \   setf sgml |
    \ endif
```

There is a `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/docbk.vim` file (which follows xml rules) but there's not a `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/sgml.vim` or `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/sgmllnx.vim` file.

If the filetype is getting set by Vim to sgml or sgmllnx, then the smartindent indentation rules will apply.  If the filetype is getting set by Vim to docbk, then the rules in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/docbk.vim` should apply.  The docbk.vim indentation rules follow xml rules, so it's very smart about indenting by tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris! The files I edit are correctly recognized as type `docbk`. It means that `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/xml.vim` is used. Now, how to modify it to *not* indent the `<screen/>` tag?

Comment: I looked into the distribution `xnl.vim` file and the function `XmlIndentGet` seems to be responsible for returning the size if the indent for the new line. If i get it correctly, Vim is calculating indent for a new line only (i.e. after ENTER is hit, for exampl). I wonder if it can change previous line as well given I hit ENTER after the `<scree>' tag. Maybe modifying the indent file is not a solution at all, but just creating a function that checks whether a type `<screen>` and the shifts that line `:left`?!?

Comment: @TomášBažant What happens if you `let b:xml_indent_open = '.\{-}<[/]\@!\(screen\)\@!'` and `let b:xml_indent_close = '.\{-}</\(screen\)\@!'` in a docbk buffer before loading `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/docbk.vim`?

Comment: _e.g._, I think you can put those two lines in `~/.vim/indent/docbk.vim`? `:help ftplugin-overrule` (1) suggests it will be loaded before the one in `$VIMRUNTIME`, so that should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, `<screen>` behaves as a normal XML tag, indented based on the previous tag's indent.